# Where is symfit?

Tags: python, model-fitting, symfit

I pip'ed symfit, (https://pythonhosted.org/symfit/) and it appears to have been installed, to wit:

```
C:\>pip install symfit

Collecting symfit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/58/0a58f7a7e39c052afe790ae0989c070e1a2d1c7d472ae3cfd4ee785f1c55/symfit-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Collecting numpy>=1.12 (from symfit)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/9a/e377ff2dabf66493ac607f6b45b4efeda898ad3fbc43b418bd7dba4a1d67/numpy-1.15.3-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl (13.5MB)

    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.5MB 975kB/s
Collecting sympy<=1.1.1 (from symfit)
Collecting scipy>=1.0 (from symfit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/ee/cfce56ea456a809b983ac4089876dbffd15233c17df7bca1e35e84c3ce95/scipy-1.1.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

Collecting mpmath>=0.19 (from sympy<=1.1.1->symfit)
Installing collected packages: numpy, mpmath, sympy, scipy, symfit

  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.1
Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot
accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

But it is not found when I try to import it into a python program, and a

```
dir /s symfit
```

from the root directory of the drive fails to find symfit.

Where did pip put it, and how can I access it?

Comment: That doesn't look installed to me. That looks like it ran into an error upgrading NumPy and aborted installation.

Comment: And there is no link on the site to contact anyone about problems, so perhaps it's just as well that I found that out early.

Comment: Hi @user1067305, I'm the founder of symfit, so maybe I can help you out ;). The problem indeed seems to be with upgrading numpy, and as it says in the traceback your version of numpy seems to be have been installed by another way, not pip. Are you using windows?

P.s. About the contacting problem, that pythonhosted link seems to be mirror of our outdated docs, I would recommend going to pypi instead and taking it from there :)
https://pypi.org/project/symfit/